# INSERT only if the same row is not older than x number of days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table @HasVal:

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
| SourceId (INT)    | HashByte VARBINARY(32)                     | DateInserted |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
| 345781            | 0xDC91932F2B1877D554F2F85ACB5709D33771D122 | 2016-12-17   |
| 345000            | 0x6368519CA666D6FF7E412835A25240A476E10CCD | 2016-12-16   |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

A new item will always be inserted 1st time.

When the item (combination of SourceId and HasByte) has come in on the same day again or less than say 3 days, I will allow it else the item will be ignored totally.

So meaning if an item with SourceId 345781 and 0xDC91932F2B1877D554F2F85ACB5709D33771D122 has come in again on the 27th Dec, I will ignore it.

Right now I have something like the below

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE, @newSourceId INT

SET @currentDate = '2016-12-21'
SET @newSourceId = 223134

DECLARE @oldHash VARBINARY(32), @oldDate DATE

SELECT TOP 1 @oldHash = HashByte, @oldDate = DateInserted FROM @HasVal
  WHERE SourceId = @newSourceId AND 
  HashByte = HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT(nvarchar(500),'some values to hash'))

IF @oldHash IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- insert new item
    INSERT INTO @HasVal VALUES 
        (@newSourceId, 
         HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT(nvarchar(500),'some values to hash')), GETDATE())
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @oldDate >= DATEADD(day, -3, @currentDate)
    BEGIN
        -- allow the item for further processing
        SELECT 'Allowed'
    END
    -- ignore the item
    ELSE SELECT 'NOT Allowed'
END
```

What I want to know is if there is a shorter way or more efficient way to do the same thing?

I have a feeling I can write shorter code in just one `SELECT` and `INSERT` statement at this point `IF @oldDate >= DATEADD(day, -3, @currentDate)`

Comment: you can use `IF EXISTS`

Comment: How about `INSERT ... FROM SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`? Tip: `HASHBYTES` is something that you should generally do once and reuse the value since cryptographic hashes are designed to be computationally expensive. Aside: Whenever you have `TOP` without `ORDER BY` you should ponder what result you expect.

Comment: @HABO INSERT ... FROM SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ... would address IF oldHash IS NULL but not IF oldDate >= DATEADD(day, -3, currentDate)? But your tips are useful!

Comment: `where not exists ( select 42 from @HasVal where SourceId = @NewSourceId and HashByte = @NewHashbyte and DateInserted >= Cast( DateAdd( day, -3, GetDate() ) as Date ) )` will check for matching rows inserted _within_ the last three days. If there are no matching rows, or only older matching rows, the result will be "truthy". (fyi: I think you have your date comparison backwards.)

Comment: awesome @HABO, i think you can post that as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this will meet your needs:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @HasVal as Table ( SourceId Int, HashByte VarBinary(32), DateInserted Date );
insert into @HasVal ( SourceId, HashByte, DateInserted ) values
  ( 345781, 0xDC91932F2B1877D554F2F85ACB5709D33771D122, '20161217' ), -- Using ISO date format.
  ( 345000, 0x6368519CA666D6FF7E412835A25240A476E10CCD, '20161216' ),
  ( 223134, 0xC17FC3F4AF82FF0E32A0A7A62BEF699B5F53D237, '20161229' ); -- Hash of 'some values to hash'.
select * from @HasVal;

-- Inputs.
declare @NewSourceId as Int = 223134;
declare @HashSource as VarChar(100) = 'some values to hash';

-- Process the data.
declare @Today as Date = GetDate();
-- Since cryptographic hashes are computationally expensive by design, hash once and use twice.
declare @NewHash as VarBinary(32) = HashBytes( 'SHA1', Cast( @HashSource as NVarChar(500) ) );
select @Today as Today, @NewHash as NewHash; -- Debugging display.

-- Insert the row if there is no existing row that matches on   SourceId   and   HashByte   and
--   was inserted within the last three days.
insert into @HasVal ( SourceId, HashByte, DateInserted )
  select @NewSourceId, @NewHash, @Today
    where not exists (
      select 42 from @HasVal
        where SourceId = @NewSourceId and HashByte = @NewHash and DateInserted >= DateAdd( day, -3, @Today ) );
if @@RowCount > 0 -- If there is additional code to execute based on whether a row was inserted.
  select 'Row inserted.' as JustSayin

select * from @HasVal; -- Display the result.
```